# Cordova android application automatic update

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a question about android app automatic update after new version release. The app is created with Cordova and jquery-mobile.

Play store and/or the android operating system checks the store automaticly for new versions and prompts the user to update the app or I have to add some code to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, both Android and iOS check for new versions (and optionally can auto update too), so you don't have to do anything on your side for this. In theory you could write code that would check the current apps version against the released version and prompt the user to open the app store, but you don't need to.